# How to add another OS entry in Wubi grub

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, grub2

I am trying to install another linux distro besides ubuntu. However, I want to retain my existing windows based loader. Currently, as per my knowledge, MsDos loads grub which then loads Ubuntu (with loop back trick).

Now, I have a new linux distro installed on /dev/sda8 (/boot for new distro) where as /root for that OS is installed on /dev/sda9.

I tried following steps
1. Add entry into 40_custom of ubuntu grub
2. update grub

But upon booting via that entry, it is not able to load the new OS and shows me blank screen. What could be the problem?

Additional data:

1. grub.cfg file of ubuntu

   > ```
   > menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-fc296be2-8c59-4f21-a3f8-47c38cd0d537' {
   >   gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
   >   insmod gzio
   >   insmod ntfs
   >   set root='hd0,msdos5'
   >   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   >     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  01CD7BB998DB0870
   >   else
   >     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 01CD7BB998DB0870
   >   fi
   >   loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
   >   set root=(loop0)
   >   linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=01CD7BB998DB0870 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
   >   initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
   > }
   > submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-fc296be2-8c59-4f21-a3f8-47c38cd0d537' {
   >   menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-19-generic-advanced-fc296be2-8c59-4f21-a3f8-47c38cd0d537'     {
   >       gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
   >       insmod gzio
   >       insmod ntfs
   >       set root='hd0,msdos5'
   >       if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   >         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  01CD7BB998DB0870
   >       else
   >         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 01CD7BB998DB0870
   >       fi
   >       loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
   >       set root=(loop0)
   >       echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-19-generic ...'
   >       linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=01CD7BB998DB0870 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
   >       echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
   >       initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
   >   }
   >   menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-19-generic-recovery-fc296be2-8c59-4f21-a3f8-47c38cd0d537' {
   >       insmod gzio
   >       insmod ntfs
   >       set root='hd0,msdos5'
   >       if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   >         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  01CD7BB998DB0870
   >       else
   >         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 01CD7BB998DB0870
   >       fi
   >       loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
   >       set root=(loop0)
   >       echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-19-generic ...'
   >       linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=01CD7BB998DB0870 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro recovery nomodeset 
   >       echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
   >       initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
   >   }
   > }
   >
   > ### END /etc/grub.d/10_lupin ###
   >
   > menuentry 'Linux, with Linux core repo kernel' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-core repo kernel-true-0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641'{
   >   load_video
   >   set gfxpayload=keep
   >   insmod gzio
   >   insmod part_msdos
   >   insmod ext2
   >   set root='hd0,msdos8'
   >   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   >     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos8 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos8  0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641
   >   else
   >     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641
   >   fi
   >   echo  'Loading Linux core repo kernel ...'
   >   linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641 ro  quiet
   >   echo  'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
   >   initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux.img
   > }
   > menuentry 'Linux, with Linux core repo kernel (Fallback initramfs)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-core repo kernel-fallback-0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641' {
   >   load_video
   >   set gfxpayload=keep
   >   insmod gzio
   >   insmod part_msdos
   >   insmod ext2
   >   set root='hd0,msdos8'
   >   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   >     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos8 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos8  0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641
   >   else
   >     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641
   >   fi
   >   echo  'Loading Linux core repo kernel ...'
   >   linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641 ro  quiet
   >   echo  'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
   >   initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
   > }
   > ```
2. lsblk

> ```
> NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
> sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
> ├─sda1    8:1    0  39.2M  0 part 
> ├─sda2    8:2    0  19.8G  0 part 
> ├─sda3    8:3    0 205.1G  0 part 
> ├─sda4    8:4    0     1K  0 part 
> ├─sda5    8:5    0 333.7G  0 part /host
> ├─sda6    8:6    0 233.4G  0 part 
> ├─sda7    8:7    0 100.4G  0 part 
> ├─sda8    8:8    0   100M  0 part 
> ├─sda9    8:9    0  14.7G  0 part 
> ├─sda10   8:10   0  21.4G  0 part 
> └─sda11   8:11   0     3G  0 part 
> sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
> loop0     7:0    0    29G  0 loop /
> ```

1. blkid

> ```
> /dev/loop0: UUID="fc296be2-8c59-4f21-a3f8-47c38cd0d537" TYPE="ext4" 
> /dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="DellUtility" UUID="5450-4444" TYPE="vfat" 
> /dev/sda2: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="78C4FAC1C4FA80A4" TYPE="ntfs" 
> /dev/sda3: LABEL="OS" UUID="DACEFCF1CEFCC6B3" TYPE="ntfs" 
> /dev/sda5: UUID="01CD7BB998DB0870" TYPE="ntfs" 
> /dev/sda6: UUID="01CD7BB99CA3F750" TYPE="ntfs" 
> /dev/sda7: LABEL="Windows 8" UUID="01CDBFB52F925F40" TYPE="ntfs" 
> /dev/sda8: UUID="cdbb5770-d29c-401d-850d-ee30a048ca5e" TYPE="ext2" 
> /dev/sda9: UUID="0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641" TYPE="ext2" 
> /dev/sda10: UUID="2e7682e5-8917-4edc-9bf9-044fea2ad738" TYPE="ext2" 
> /dev/sda11: UUID="6081da70-d622-42b9-b489-309f922b284e" TYPE="swap
> ```

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need any extra data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to loopback in the entry you have made.
It should be like this.

```
menuentry 'Linux, with Linux core repo kernel' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-core repo kernel-true-0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641'{
  load_video
  set gfxpayload=keep
  insmod gzio
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='hd0,msdos8'
  if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos8 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos8  0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641
  else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641
  fi

loopback loop1 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
      set root=(loop1)

  echo  'Loading Linux core repo kernel ...'
  linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=0f490b6c-e92d-42f0-88e1-0bd3c0d27641 ro  quiet
  echo  'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
  initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
```